# How to map from an Array into a Google react Chart (React)?

Tags: reactjs, calendar

I actually face a problem with react I did not expect so far. Actually I have a google-react-chart Calender and an array, that I have parsed from different Date formats in one. Now i want to parse through my array and to map it's data to my google-react-chart calender. Unfortunatley I did most of my coding on the web in php so far, and guys, I don't have any idea how I can bring this construction to work :))

I tried to replace my hard coded data with a mapping function, but - as you may know - that only leads to a parsing error :)

So my simple question is: How can I process my arrayData to my Google react chart calender?

```
//did not work
mydateArray.map((item) =>{JSON.parse{item)}
```

[image: Image from myArry - Output in brwoser Console]

[image: An Image of my Google-react-chart Calender in plain Text]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to parse a string, instead of a JSON object.

If you are getting this array from PHP, try passing it as a json_encode($variable), but not with the new Date() class. You can just pass it as the date string itself in the first position and the amount in the second position of the array;

Assuming you have the date and the data as something like this in PHP (before the json_encode):

```
$variable = [['MM/DD/YYYY', 50126],['MM/DD/YYY', 50126], and so on];
```

After you pass to React your PHP variable (via fetch or the dataset),
you can do something like:

```
mydateArray = JSON.parse(phpVariable);
```

and THEN, you can map it:

```
mydateArray.map(item => [new Date(item[0]), item[1]);
```

Just some Date warnings:
- Date in javascript must be constructed using Month/Day/Year, unfortunatelly. There is no createFromFormat, like PHP.
- The date ranges from 0 to 11, so october (10th month) must be written as 09/day/year, and so on.